# GCP, Composer, Airflow, Operators

Tags: google-cloud-platform, airflow, google-cloud-composer

As Google Cloud Composer uses Cloud Storage to store Apache Airflow DAGs. However, where the operators are stored ? I am getting an error as below:

> Broken DAG: [/home/airflow/gcs/dags/example_pubsub_flow.py] cannot import name PubSubSubscriptionCreateOperator.

Answer (score 1):

This operator was added in **Airflow 1.10.0** . As of today, Cloud Composer is still using **Airflow 1.9.0**, hence this operator is not available yet. You can add this as a plugin.

Comment: Your suggestion seems to be the right solution intuitively but it can get a bit cumbersome as there are many dependencies between contrib packages and it may require to "migrate" many packages as I understand that the plugin boilerplate must be added to all the involved files. do you know of any repo where contrib files can be found in plugin format?

Answer (score 1):

apparently, according to the following post in [this message in  the Composer Google Group](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/cloud-composer-discuss/MZMmxdPbXaQ/1SufZgzqBwAJ) list, to install as a plugin the contrib is not needed to add the Plugin boilerplate. 
It is enough with registering the plugins via this command:

```
gcloud beta composer environments storage plugins import --environment dw --location us-central1 --source=custom_operators.py
```

See [here](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/concepts/plugins) for detail.

The drawback is that if your contrib operator uses others you will have to copy also those and modify the way they are imported in python, using:

```
from my_custom_operator import MyCustomOperator
```

instead of:

```
from airflow.contrib.operators.my_custom_operator import MyCustomOperator
```